# In Perl, if possible, how do I pass a generic diamond (<>) filehandle to a subroutine?

Tags: perl, filehandle

I have a script that reads input serially on the fly as another job outputs it, and is expected to modify and return it.  To do more complex modifications, I'd like to be able to capture this input and pass it to a subroutine, which would then return an object to my base script, where I could modify the object as needed, and then write it back out.  Right now, my code looks something like this:

```
while (my $line = <>) {
    # Do stuff here to build object
    # When end of record, call writeObject
    # Start new object unless eof
}

sub writeObject {
    # Iterate over object and print to STDOUT
}
```

I'd like to take the first while loop and convert it into a subroutine that I can then put, along with `writeObject`, into a small module that I can reuse.  What I think I need to do is somehow pass `<>` to this new subroutine, `buildObject`.  I'd then build new scripts that import `buildObject` and `writeObject`, and implement a `modifyObject` routine that will change from script to script.  The other two pieces should be completely reusable, as those parts of the process never change.  Optimally, the new routine would look something like this:

```
sub buildObjects {
    my ($input) = @_;
    my @objects = ();
    while (<$input>) {
        # Build object, push to @objects when done
    }
    return \@objects;
}
```

A script using this would look something like this:

```
my $obj = buildObjects(<>);

foreach my $object (@$obj) {
    $object = modifyObject($object);
    writeObject($object);
}
```

Comment: `<>` is the `readline` operator, not a file handle. It will read from files specified on the command line if there are any, otherwise it reads from standard input. It sounds like the other job is passing data through a pipe. Your file handle is `STDIN` and you can pass it by reference as `buildObjects(\*STDIN)`. But I don't see why your subroutine can't just read using `<>` as your original code does. Surely you're not expecting input from multiple different sources?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<>` is short for `<ARGV>`, so

```
buildObjects(\*ARGV);
```

---

Tip: `ARGV` is a magical file handle. Function that expect an underlying  system file handle won't be able to work with it. That's not the case for you, though.

Comment: `perldoc perlvar`: "Note that currently ARGV only has its magical effect within the `<>` operator; elsewhere it is just a plain filehandle corresponding to the last file opened by `<>`. ***In particular, passing `\*ARGV` as a parameter to a function that expects a filehandle may not cause your function to automatically read the contents of all the files in `@ARGV`***."

Comment: Said function does use the `<>` operator, though, so the warning isn't applicable here.

Comment: I agree, but this is a good caution for the OP to keep in mind. I did vote your answer up.